# Display set values in redis using node

Tags: node.js, redis

I am stuck with a simple basic redis node program. The code is

```
var redis = require("redis"), client = redis.createClient();`
client.on("error", function (err) {
console.log("Error " + err);
});
client.sadd("string key1", "Hello1", redis.print);
client.sadd("string key1", "Hello2", redis.print);
client.sadd("string key2", "Hi1", redis.print);
client.sadd("string key2", "Hi2", redis.print);
client.smembers("string key1");
}
```

How to display the added sets in console. I need output like

`"string key1" Hello1, Hello2`

`"string key2" hi1, hi2`

Please help me with the code. Please

Answer (score 0):

```
client.multi()
    .smembers("string key1")
    .smembers("string key2")
    .exec(function (err, replies) {
    console.log("MULTI got " + replies.length + " replies");
    replies.forEach(function (reply, index) {
        console.log("Reply " + index + ": " + reply.toString());
    });
    });
```

More examples here https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/tree/master/examples